Optimizing postgres query / approach for caching complex aggregations for large datasets
I have an extremely large table of transactions with hundreds of millions of rows and I need to calculate their sum total grouped by various columns up to various points in time. Queries were getting too slow, so I added another table where I store cached totals at points in time.
Here's a simplified schema:

transactions table: timestamp (datetime), item_id (int), total (numeric)
cached_totals table: point_in_time (datetime), item_id (int), aggregated_total (numeric)

I use change data capture, calculate totals between the last cached set of totals and a given end time, and add them to to the previous values. As long as we guarantee that we update cached totals chronologically, everything works ok, but calculating and updating these cached values is also slower than I'd like.
Here's a simplified query that I use to calculate a new set of totals to upsert into the cached_totals table.
with prev as (
  select
    item_id,
    aggregated_total
  from cached_totals
  where point_in_time = %(start_point)s
),
curr as (
  select
    item_id,
    sum(total) as aggregated_total
  from transactions
  where
    timestamp > %(start_point)s
    and timestamp <= %(end_point)s
)
select
  %(end_point)s as point_in_time,
  coalesce(prev.item_id, curr.item_id) as item_id,
  coalesce(prev.aggregated_total, 0) + coalesce(curr.aggregated_total, 0) as aggregated_total
from prev
full outer join curr on prev.item_id = curr.item_id;

There are a few more columns we use for grouping and aggregations that I've left out for the sake of simplicity. Is there a better query structure than the full outer join? Maybe window functions? There can be rows in the prev subquery that aren't in curr subquery, and vice-versa.
Is there a better overall approach to this problem?

Could you please share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? And the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this statement? All in plain text, as an update of your question. And what PostgreSQL version do you use?
